# How to insert a CLOB column using dbUtils in oracle10g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, clob

I can insert a clob using:

```
Reader clobReader = new StringReader(fileString);
stmt.setCharacterStream(1, clobReader, clob.length());
int num = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I want to use [dbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/index.html) to finish it.

```
run.update(conn, "insert into fileservice(id,filedata)values('1234','ddd',?)",new Object[]{fileString});
```

fileString is a large String.

I encounter 32k limitations for clob: setString can only process strings of less than 32766 chararacters.

How to handle a CLOB object using dbUtils?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the 32K limit try adding this:

```
connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("SetBigStringTryClob", "true");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBCUrl, connectionProperties);
```

in case you are working with Oracle, you can cast PreparedStatement to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement which gives you more options to work with